# Can 訂正 be used like this? 訂正しろ、今すぐ。

Tags: usage

From here: https://nihongomaster.com/japanese/dictionary/word/41934/teisei

> 訂正しろ、今すぐ。 Translation: Take that back, right now!

("Take that back" as in taking back what you said.)

Can 訂正 be used this way? Is this phrase commonly used?

Answer (score 4):

[A dictionary entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%A8%82%E6%AD%A3/#jn-150116) has the example : 発言を訂正する. So it can be used in the situation like the question. But I would use 取り消せ to mean *take that back*.

Possibly, if you have in mind how it should be corrected, 訂正しろ might sound natural.